# Can finalize be called after a constructor throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

Are there any details on whether or not an object is cleaned up using `finalize()` if that object's constructor thew an exception.

When this method is called is notoriously ill defined.  According to the manual:

> The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will
>   invoke the finalize method for any given object. It is guaranteed,
>   however, that the thread that invokes finalize will not be holding any
>   user-visible synchronization locks when finalize is invoked. If an
>   uncaught exception is thrown by the finalize method, the exception is
>   ignored and finalization of that object terminates.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29

I've not been able to trigger the finalize method in this way. Does anyone know if it is garunteed NOT to be called or if it is in some cases called after the constructor failed to initialize the object (thew an exception).

I ask this because I have an object which must not be cleaned up twice.  I'm trying to understand if it is safe to clean up before throwing the exception or if I must leave a marker for `finalize()` to effectively skip and do nothing.

Comment: +1 I suspect it is something you will need to check for as different JVMs might behave differently.

Comment: Using `finalize` is evil.

Comment: @Peter the JLS is quite specific, an object is finalizable once the constructor for the [base] Object is completed successfully.

Comment: @JasonPyeron Excellent clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My test shows that it can

```
public class Test1 {

    Test1() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("finalized");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            new Test1();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

prints

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at test.Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:24)
finalized
```

it is on Java HostSpot Client VM 1.7.0_03

Comment: That's very helpful!  Could you edit into your answer which JVM you tried this on and I'll accept it.  Many thanks!

Comment: this is because the implied super() did not throw an exception.

Answer (score 10):

According to section [12.6.1. Implementing Finalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) of the JLS:

> An object o is not finalizable until its constructor has invoked the constructor for Object on o and that invocation has completed successfully (that is, without throwing an exception).

If your constructor throws an exception *after* the Object constructor completes, then your object should be finalizable, so `finalize()` could still be called.

There's a good example stepping through object construction in section [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) that shows exactly when the Object constructor is called.

Comment: That means in class X X(){super();} the super() call to Object has completed without exception. The Object class has the glue code to register the heap allocation, allocated by new, for garbage collection.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the above remark (the definition of _finalizable_) 1st appeared in the 3rd edition of the JLS (Java 1.5), but Java 1.5 still allowed the finalizer to run even though the `Object` constructor was never invoked (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159455)). This bug was only fixed in Java 1.6.

Comment: @Bass and there’s even a JVM option to enable the old behavior, whose exact name I do not remember, unfortunately.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! I believe it to be [RegisterFinalizersAtInit](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html#RegisterFinalizersAtInit).

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate more clearly:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static class LifeBoat extends RuntimeException
    {
        private Test1 passenger;
        public Test1 getPassenger(){return passenger;}
        public LifeBoat(Test1 passenger){this.passenger=passenger;}
    }

    Test1() {
        super(); //once this is finished, there is an Object to GC per JLS 12.6.1. 
        throw new LifeBoat(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("finalized");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            new Test1();
        } catch (LifeBoat e) {
            Test1 obj;
            obj=e.getPassenger();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

prints

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at test.Test1.<init>(Test1.java:13)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:24)
test.Test1@6dc8f3cd
finalized
```