# Does the JVM invoke finalizers for uninitialized objects?

Tags: java, jvm, finalizer, jls

Consider the following code:

```
final class FinalizerTest {
    private static volatile FinalizerTest sharedInstance;

    private FinalizerTest() {
        this(throwNew());
    }

    private FinalizerTest(final String ignored) {
    }

    private static String throwNew() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("finalize()'d from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        sharedInstance = this;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                new FinalizerTest();
            } catch (final UnsupportedOperationException ignored) {
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.gc();
        }

        System.out.println(sharedInstance);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when a no-argument constructor attempts to evaluate an argument for the other constructor, so object initialization completes abnormally.

I observe that under Java 1.5 and below, the finalizer is invoked (which allows an uninitialized instance to leak), while in Java 1.6 onwards it is not (heap size is unlikely to be the cause as I tested both large objects and small heaps).

Does the *JVM* invoke finalizers for uninitialized objects?

Can you point me to the corresponding change in the *JLS*?

Comment: @Radiodef The GC happened in both cases (if I allowed the constructor of `java.lang.Object` to complete successfully, objects were finalized even under 1.6+). Instead, there's indeed a difference in the 3rd Ed. of the [JLS, §12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1), introducing the definition of _finalizable_ (see my comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483656/1343979)).